# Ceramic Capacitors

Tags: capacitor, automotive

What is the difference between General purpose and Automotive grade ceramic capacitors, if they have the same capacitance, temperature coefficient and operating temperature. is there a manufacturing or design difference or are they the same except the Automotive ones go through additional screening?

Comment: One is twice as expensive. Easier if you give two datasheets to compare, otherwise we don't know which ones you are looking at.

Comment: Since most of the automotive grade ones should be AEC-Q200 compliant, there should be a design or manufacturing difference. These differences should lead to some differences in terms of characteristics *(e.g. Z/ESR vs Frequency)*. There are also "Flexible MLCC"s (Google it). They are widely used in automotive.

Comment: I believe automotive grades have better gas mileage ;)  j/k but they have higher standards for quality factors like traceability etc. Considering the cost of failures and lawsuits, and fact that caps with ripple current or voltage stress are top failure components, I’d choose reliable parts, design and process as my motto anyday over the dirt cheapest parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it really means is; you are maybe unlikely to find any Chinese Supplier qualified to AEC-Q200 due to quality control, traceability. They will be Japanese companies who take quality most seriously like ... Panasonic, Toyo Yuden, Rubicon for caps.

```
AEC-Q100: Integrated circuits (ICs)
AEC-Q101: Discrete semiconductor components (transistors, diodes, etc.)
AEC-Q200: Passive components (capacitors, inductors, etc.)
```

They include temperature grades from 105~150C for under the hood or interior etc.

MTBF drops 50% /+10’C rise , so life tests at elevated temps are mandatory and bunch of other stress tests,